# How to create a sliding menu programatically in android

Tags: android

What is the best way to have a sliding menu for my `MainActivity` ? or is there any better way

**EDIT** : During the processe i do that :

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

and after that :

`setContentView(myView);`

And what i want is : How can i put a sliding menu in `myView`

Comment: _programaly_ on google is something arabic, what does it has to do with programming?

Comment: Not able to get your point,explain it in a better way.

Comment: What I mean is : a view create in the main activitiy

Comment: If u want an hint, rewrite your question explaining exactly what you want and what you tried

Comment: "_a sliding menu_" is the navigation drawer?

Comment: Thank you Charuka I try to express myself at best but my English is not very good

Comment: @Charuka Where do you see **insults**?

Comment: @Charuka It's OK. It can happen to overlook things sometimes ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try the builtin `Navigation Drawer Activity` in androids studio

File->New->Activity->Navigation Drawer Activity
[image]